# dropkick js and body background error

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-dropkick

Hey I'm using Dropkick js on my website, but for some reason the body background image is affected and become buggy. The background is a large image that is fixed and its position is set to "cover".

```
body {
    background:url('IMAGEURL');
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/NR9L2/1/

When you scroll down, the image does not appear fixed, and when you are scrolled down and activate the dropdown menu the image appears to "correct" its position.

I am using Google Chrome on a PC.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same problem. It only happens in Chrome so I'm guessing it's a Chrome bug. You are right - it's the `background-size:cover;` with combination of `background-attachment:fixed;` that messes it up. Using a fixed div as bg with no attachment doesn't help either.

The way I resolved it was by using one of the following plugins:

http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/fullscreen-background-jquery-plugins/

The down side is it uses jQuery to resize not CSS3.

Comment: Thank you. It also seems that Firefox is a bit buggy as well. Any recommendation for those plugins?

Comment: The easiest and lightest one is [Full Size Bg](http://bavotasan.com/download-manager.php?id=25) - 1KB (minified)  

To load it: $("#background").fullBg();  


You could use [Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) if you want a slideshow.